# add_post_meta tag is not working

Tags: jquery

I used add_post_meta tag in my script.it's not working. my problem is, if user is logged in & click the download, user id is to be save in database.
but it's not working.i added my code.please check me and tell.

```
<input type="hidden" id="download" value="<?php the_field('download_pdf');?>"></br>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id();?>"></br>



<?php       $pid=wpsc_the_product_id();
$res=mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM  `wp_posts` WHERE post_parent='".$pid."' AND post_mime_type='application/pdf'  AND post_type = 'wpsc-product-file'");
  $key_1_values=mysql_fetch_array($res);
//echo $key_1_values["ID"];
 $post_7 = get_post($key_1_values["ID"], ARRAY_A);
$pdflink = $post_7['guid'];

       ?>

<!--user_id-->
<?php 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
    $user_id == $current_user->ID;</br>
?>




<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#download").click(function() {

<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
 $user_id == $current_user->ID;
 add_post_meta(wpsc_the_product_id(),'download',$user_id);
}
 ?>
});
});
```

Comment: Do you mix javascript with PHP code?
javascript is client side, PHP is server side.

with PHP you can write code javascript that execute later (respect PHP), so it doesn't work.

Comment: Then how can i write this code?can you help me?

Comment: How to write Php inside javascript? anyone

Comment: You should create a php page (or script) to process the request and use add_post_meta

for example, in this page each row you should create a link with params in querystring, like so:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#download").click(function() {
window.location.href = 'page.php?post_id=<?php echo $post_id; ?>&user_id=<?php echo $user_id; ?>';
}); });

I have not try this code, the important is that do you should use PHP only for write Javascript code (print text) not interact each other in the same page.